# Как получить название улицы в Украине на русском языке в Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps-api

В большинстве случаев, особенно в больших городах в ответе возвращается название на украинском.

Вот допустим такой запрос:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=50.4517418%2C+30.5265072&language=ru
```

возвращает название на украинском, несмотря на параметр `language=ru`

Можно ли получить название улицы в Украине на русском?

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, никак. Теперь Гугл показывает улицы в Украине только на укр. языке. К слову, то же самое актульно и для некоторых других стран, например посмотрите Казахстан, Литва...

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/134375)

Comment: @ilyaplot, почему это не ответ? Вопрос был задан «Как?...», это же сообщение отвечает «Никак». В комментариях ему точно не место, только в ответах.

Comment: @Arhad данный ответ никаким образом не поможет автору в решении проблемы. Нужно предлагать варианты решения вопроса, а не говорить, что ничего не получится.

Comment: @ilyaplot "никак" это ответ (тем более с примерами). Он поможет автору вопроса тем, что тот не будет тщетно искать "как", а перейдет к альтернативным решениям. А вот отсутствие какого бы то ни было ответа вообще - вот это бесполезно.

Comment: Можно добавить вот эту ссылку с подтверждением от Google: https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2014/11/localization-of-street-addresses-in.html